# Firebase Authentication- Facebook login does not return the user information

Tags: javascript, firebase, cordova, firebase-authentication

I have a cordova project and I am getting null user after authenticating with Facebook

Here is the flow..

1. I am redirected to login screen
2. Enter Email and password
3. Shown a screen to confirm my login with a continue button
4. I am then redirected back to the app after selecting the "continue" button
5. Result -- user = null

Cordova version -8.1.2
Firebase SDK  -- 5.9.0

Here is my button code

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
$rootScope.user  = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if ($rootScope.user) {
  $rootScope.openCommonAlertModal({
  title: 'Sign in Success',
  details: "user log in as "+$rootScope.user.email
 }); 
 $scope.closeSignIn();
 $rootScope.$broadcast('signInEvent');
 } else {
   firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function () {
    return firebase.auth().getRedirectResult();
 }).then(function (result) {
 var token = result.credential.accessToken;
 $rootScope.user = result.user;
 $rootScope.openCommonAlertModal({
    title: 'Sign in Success',
    details: "user log in as "+$rootScope.user.email
  }); 
  $scope.closeSignIn();
  $rootScope.$broadcast('signInEvent');
}).catch(function (error) {
 var errorCode = error.code;
 var errorMessage = error.message;

 $rootScope.openCommonAlertModal({
     title: 'Sign in failure',
      details: errorMessage + errorCode
  }); 
});
}
```